# data is not submitting into db:laravel-5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm new to laravel and trying to save data into db but nothing happens. I just want to save it into db.

**controller:**

```php
       public function store(Request $request)
       {
        $request->validate([
            'date' => 'required',
            'start_time' => 'required',
            'end_time' => 'required',
            'time_slot' => 'required',
        ]);

        Form::create(request(['date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'time_slot']));

        $data->save();
        return view('form.index');
       }
```

**blade file:**

```html
       <table class="table table-hover mt-5">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Start Time</th>
                <th scope="col">End Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Time Slice</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <input type="date" name="date">
                </th>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" name="start_time" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" name="end_time" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <select name="time_slot">
                    <option value="1">15 min</option>
                    <option value="2">30 min</option>
                    <option value="3">45 min</option>
                    <option value="4">1 hr</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <button type="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Data</button>
```

I'm using resource route for it.

Comment: `$data->save();` do you see any `$data` variable in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
            $request->validate([
                'date' => 'required',
                'start_time' => 'required',
                'end_time' => 'required',
                'time_slot' => 'required',
            ]);

            Form::create($request->all());

            return view('form.index');
     }
```

blade file:

```php
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('form.store' }}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <table class="table table-hover mt-5">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Start Time</th>
                <th scope="col">End Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Time Slice</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <input type="date" name="date">
                </th>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" name="start_time" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" name="end_time" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <select name="time_slot">
                    <option value="1">15 min</option>
                    <option value="2">30 min</option>
                    <option value="3">45 min</option>
                    <option value="4">1 hr</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Data</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: put your front code with `<form>` tag in your question

Comment: complete code of controller paste.ofcode.org/H4YkRwVZAQEkVHb8LL6E3d

Comment: Check i updated my answer just you copy paste in you IDE and run it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196196/discussion-between-karan-and-programmer0001).

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options to save it in database: 
1---------------------------

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
    $request->validate([
        'date' => 'required',
        'start_time' => 'required',
        'end_time' => 'required',
        'time_slot' => 'required',
    ]);

    $form = new Form(); //make new object from your model
    $form->date = $request['date'];  //each of the DB field fill with $request fields
    $form->start_time = $request['start_time'];
    $form->end_time = $request['end_time'];
    $form->time_slot = $request'time_slot'];
    $form->save(); //Save this to your DB

    return view('form.index');
   }
```

2-------------------------------Recomended 
in this way you need to do something in your model
Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Form extends Model
{
    protected $table = "forms"; //table name in your DB
    protected $fillable = ['date','start_date','end_date','time_slot']; //your fields in DB table that you want to fill them
}
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
    $request->validate([
        'date' => 'required',
        'start_time' => 'required',
        'end_time' => 'required',
        'time_slot' => 'required',
    ]);

    $form = new Form(); //make new object from your model
    $form->create($request->all()); //NOTE:your fields in view should be the same name with your fields in DB, i mean for example you should get the start_date from an input that it's name is start_date, <input name="start_date">  

    return view('form.index');
   }
```

i hope this helps you !

Comment: in which way ? first or second way ?

Comment: still not saving

Comment: now General error: 1364 Field 'date' doesn't have a default value

Comment: it means your form(view) does not send the "date" value to your controller with $request and DB needs the date value to save, check your form and your $request values that is comming from view

Comment: please send me your Model,view,controller,routes to my email, `reza.sh_rs@yahoo.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196200/discussion-between-programmer0001-and-reza-sh).